# Model's static methods are causing "undefined method" erros when running through custom rake tasks in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, rake

My rake looks like this:

```
task :cron => :environment do
  Email.signup_email_reminder  
end
```

And my Email.signup_email_reminder methods looks like this:

```
class Email
include ActiveModel::Validations  
include ActiveModel::Conversion  
extend ActiveModel::Naming
.
.
.
def self.signup_email_reminder
  User.any_in(:status => [:status1, :status2]).each do |user|      
    puts Data.get_country_code(user.locale).upcase
  end
end
.
.
.
end
```

the method get_country_code is a static class in the model Data:

```
class Data

  def self.get_country_code(locale)
    .
    .
  end
.
.
.
end
```

But every time I run the rake I get an error saying that the get_country_code method does not exist :(

```
$ rake cron --trace
(in /Volumes/alexandre.ponsin/Documents/Project/TextMaster.com)
** Invoke cron (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute cron
rake aborted!
undefined method `get_country_code' for Data:Class
```

I don't know what to do here :(

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is namespace collision. There's already a class called Data, so you may want to think about renaming your model.

```
$: rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
ruby-1.8.7-p330 :001 > Data
 => Data
```

Comment: You're a life saver ! Indeed that was the issue, renaming my class into CustomData made it work ! I have been struggling with this for hours.